# Errors compiling WolfSSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, amqp, coap

I'm a newbie,and I'm trying to compile static library for Click Router, currently wolfSSL, i'm on Ubuntu 17.10

i'm following these steps:

1. Clone wolfSSL GIT repo:

   ```
   cd clickDynCOAP
   git clone https://github.com/fvdnabee/wolfssl.git
   cd wolfssl
   git checkout click
   ```
2. compile wolfSSL:

   ```
   [cd wolfssl]
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure CFLAGS='-DWOLFSSL_STATIC_PSK' CXXFLAGS='-DWOLFSSL_STATIC_PSK' --enable-dtls --enable-aesccm --enable-psk --enable-static --enable-debug --enable-ipv6 --enable-ecc --enable-supportedcurves --enable-dsa --enable-tlsx --enable-opensslextra  --enable-fastmath
   make -j4
   ```

and gives me the following errors

```
stefano@stefano-Lenovo-Y50:~/click/click-lpwan/clickDynCOAP/wolfssl$ make -j4
make -j9  all-am
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/stefano/click/click-lpwan/clickDynCOAP/wolfssl'
  CC       wolfcrypt/src/src_libwolfssl_la-signature.lo
  CC       src/src_libwolfssl_la-ssl.lo
  CC       examples/selectserver/selectserver.o
  CC       examples/client/client.o
  CC       examples/server/server.o
  CC       examples/echoclient/echoclient.o
  CC       examples/client/testsuite_testsuite_test-client.o
  CC       src/src_libwolfssl_la-internal.lo
  CC       examples/echoserver/echoserver.o
In file included from examples/client/client.c:52:0:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
In file included from ./cyassl/test.h:3:0,
                 from examples/selectserver/selectserver.c:5:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
In file included from ./cyassl/test.h:3:0,
                 from examples/echoclient/echoclient.c:51:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
In file included from ./cyassl/test.h:3:0,
                 from examples/server/server.c:54:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
In file included from examples/client/client.c:52:0:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
In file included from ./cyassl/test.h:3:0,
                 from examples/echoserver/echoserver.c:48:
./wolfssl/test.h: In function ‘build_addr’:
./wolfssl/test.h:600:14: error: comparison between pointer and zero character constant [-Werror=pointer-compare]
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
              ^~
./wolfssl/test.h:600:9: note: did you mean to dereference the pointer?
     if (peer == INADDR_ANY)
         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2396: recipe for target 'examples/selectserver/selectserver.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/selectserver/selectserver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2396: recipe for target 'examples/echoclient/echoclient.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/echoclient/echoclient.o] Error 1
Makefile:2396: recipe for target 'examples/echoserver/echoserver.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/echoserver/echoserver.o] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:3015: recipe for target 'examples/client/testsuite_testsuite_test-client.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/client/testsuite_testsuite_test-client.o] Error 1
Makefile:2396: recipe for target 'examples/server/server.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/server/server.o] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2396: recipe for target 'examples/client/client.o' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/client/client.o] Error 1
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c: In function ‘wc_SignatureVerify’:
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c:195:20: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 if (ret < 0) {
                    ^
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c:202:13: note: here
             case WC_SIGNATURE_TYPE_RSA:
             ^~~~
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c: In function ‘wc_SignatureGenerate’:
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c:312:20: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 if (ret < 0) {
                    ^
wolfcrypt/src/signature.c:319:13: note: here
             case WC_SIGNATURE_TYPE_RSA:
             ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2609: recipe for target 'wolfcrypt/src/src_libwolfssl_la-signature.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [wolfcrypt/src/src_libwolfssl_la-signature.lo] Error 1
src/ssl.c: In function ‘wolfSSL_connect’:
src/ssl.c:6866:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: CLIENT_HELLO_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6868:9: note: here
         case CLIENT_HELLO_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:6895:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: HELLO_AGAIN");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6897:9: note: here
         case HELLO_AGAIN :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:6943:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: HELLO_AGAIN_REPLY");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6945:9: note: here
         case HELLO_AGAIN_REPLY :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:6966:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6968:9: note: here
         case FIRST_REPLY_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:6980:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_FIRST");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6982:9: note: here
         case FIRST_REPLY_FIRST :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:6992:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_SECOND");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:6994:9: note: here
         case FIRST_REPLY_SECOND :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7005:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_THIRD");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7007:9: note: here
         case FIRST_REPLY_THIRD :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7014:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_FOURTH");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7016:9: note: here
         case FIRST_REPLY_FOURTH :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7034:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: SECOND_REPLY_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7036:9: note: here
         case SECOND_REPLY_DONE:
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c: In function ‘wolfSSL_accept’:
src/ssl.c:7229:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state ACCEPT_CLIENT_HELLO_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7231:9: note: here
         case ACCEPT_CLIENT_HELLO_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7233:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state ACCEPT_FIRST_REPLY_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7235:9: note: here
         case ACCEPT_FIRST_REPLY_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7241:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state SERVER_HELLO_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7243:9: note: here
         case SERVER_HELLO_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7252:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state CERT_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7254:9: note: here
         case CERT_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7263:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state CERT_STATUS_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7265:9: note: here
         case CERT_STATUS_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7272:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state KEY_EXCHANGE_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7274:9: note: here
         case KEY_EXCHANGE_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7284:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state CERT_REQ_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7286:9: note: here
         case CERT_REQ_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7293:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state SERVER_HELLO_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7295:9: note: here
         case SERVER_HELLO_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7304:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state  ACCEPT_SECOND_REPLY_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7306:9: note: here
         case ACCEPT_SECOND_REPLY_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7316:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state  TICKET_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7318:9: note: here
         case TICKET_SENT:
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7324:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state  CHANGE_CIPHER_SENT");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7326:9: note: here
         case CHANGE_CIPHER_SENT :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7333:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state ACCEPT_FINISHED_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7335:9: note: here
         case ACCEPT_FINISHED_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/ssl.c:7344:13: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             WOLFSSL_MSG("accept state ACCEPT_THIRD_REPLY_DONE");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/ssl.c:7346:9: note: here
         case ACCEPT_THIRD_REPLY_DONE :
         ^~~~
src/internal.c: In function ‘ProcessReply’:
src/internal.c:9081:16: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             if (!ssl->options.dtls) {
                ^
src/internal.c:9168:9: note: here
         case getRecordLayerHeader:
         ^~~~
src/internal.c:9192:39: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             ssl->options.processReply = getData;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:9195:9: note: here
         case getData:
         ^~~~
src/internal.c:9213:22: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
             startIdx = ssl->buffers.inputBuffer.idx;  /* in case > 1 msg per */
             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:9216:9: note: here
         case runProcessingOneMessage:
         ^~~~
src/internal.c: In function ‘SendServerKeyExchange’:
src/internal.c:16080:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_BUILD;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:16083:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_BUILD:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:16862:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_VERIFY;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:16865:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_VERIFY:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:16956:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_FINALIZE;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:16959:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_FINALIZE:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:17024:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_END;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:17027:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_END:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c: In function ‘DoClientKeyExchange’:
src/internal.c:18460:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_BUILD;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:18463:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_BUILD:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:18899:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_VERIFY;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:18902:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_VERIFY:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:18995:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_FINALIZE;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:18998:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_FINALIZE:
             ^~~~
src/internal.c:19033:44: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
                 ssl->options.keyShareState = KEYSHARE_END;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/internal.c:19036:13: note: here
             case KEYSHARE_END:
             ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2840: recipe for target 'src/src_libwolfssl_la-internal.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [src/src_libwolfssl_la-internal.lo] Error 1
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2861: recipe for target 'src/src_libwolfssl_la-ssl.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [src/src_libwolfssl_la-ssl.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/stefano/click/click-lpwan/clickDynCOAP/wolfssl'
Makefile:1720: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what could i do?

Comment: For responses from the wolfSSL team try adding the flag "wolfSSL" on future questions!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using git clone https://github.com/fvdnabee/wolfssl.git instead of the wolfSSL actual source?

https://github.com/wolfssl/wolfssl.git

The version on that fork is v3.9.8 which is from April of 2015. Could you try this same test but use the wolfSSL actual branch and let us know your results?

- K